# How can I install / debug applications on nanopi m4 Android board?

Tags: usb, debug, adb

I have a nanopi m4 Android board, usb type c port for charging and data (and debugging maybe), four usb 3.0 ports, Android 8.1

I need to use adb,

## what I have tried

1. use the charging / data port (usb type c) for debugging, the board couldn't boot, it goes through a loop trying to boot, I guess because of not enough delivered power;
2. looking for the debug over Wifi feature in the Android settings, but I didn't find this option.

## Question

What other debugging options do I have?

## This might help

- I can put an App in SD card and use it
- I can host a temporary web server to get the app to the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem Solved

Somebody just figured out how to do it: power the board using two power bins and use the usb-c for debugging.